# Python3.9 : What is the correct way of deploying an application in respect of the python sys path

Tags: python, deployment, path

I have a standalone program written in Python. At one point I decided to organize this program into packages but the interpreter did not recognize the packages anymore. This seems to be a classic drawback in Python.

```
Python 'No module named' error; 'package' is not a package
```

I fixed this by extending the system path like following code block inside the base dunder __ init__.py file:

```
import sys
import os

dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))


sys.path.extend(['{}/example_package'.format(dirname)])
```

This setup works, so I'm happy. But this does not feel like the right way to organize an application. I can't find much information on the net about deploying python software.

My questions: Is this method of path inclusion accepted when the program will be deployed and released as a standalone application? Is this a practical working method if I would decide to convert the python code into binaries?

Comment: you have to add `dirname`, not `dirname/example_package`

Comment: addin to `sys.path` is standard method for this problem.

Comment: TY. I've got a nested packages structure. dirname alone does not seem to work.  Would you care formulating an answer?